# I am trying to place the elements below the div elements

Tags: html, css

I positioned two div elements side-by-side by using float= left;
But buttons are getting displayed beside the div elements.
I want the button elements right below the two div elements which were placed side- by-side.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Also, we can't help you without examples of your code.

Comment: You surely used `float: left;` on both boxes and then placed some input buttons. Use `clear: left;` on the last box. although you should consider putting the buttons in a new `div` since inputs are displayed inline by default. Always post your code...

Answer (score 1):

When you use `float:left` property then the div's height and width are set by either of the following

1. amount of space it's content html elements require
2. applied css height and width.

hence say if your screen if too big and space is left out on the sides then the next element (if it can be fitted in that space) is rendered (if it requires more then it would appear on the next line).

hence now regarding your problem there are two possible solution's

1. > Increase the widths of your div so that it takes most of the screen width.(**mostly never used** as it might look ugly on big screens)

   but if u want to go by this approach the setting the width's in percent can do the job.

   [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/j7X3S/1/)
2. > use the `clear:both` property of css (**mostly used**)

   for it's explanation you have to read it's [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

   i would suggest you go by this approach

   [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/j7X3S/2/)